# Give an explicit formula to the solution of $\dfrac{dP}{dt}=rP(M-P)(P-m)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> $$\dfrac{dP}{dt}=rP(M-P)(P-m)$$Write down the explicit formula for $P$ in terms of $r,M,m$ and the integral constant. $r,M,m$ are positve real numbers.

I solved it by separation of variables(and partial fractions) and got $-\dfrac{1}{Mm}lnP - \dfrac{1}{M(M-m)}ln(M-P)+\dfrac{1}{m(M-m)}ln(P-m) = rt + C$, how can I express $P$ in terms of $r,M,m,C$?

Comment: You cannot do it explicitely.

Comment: we can not find an explicit solution